# How do I add grant_type, username and password to API request in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, webrequest

I'm trying to figure out how to get an authorization token from the [BIC - BOXTECH API](https://bic-boxtech.github.io/ManualTests/ManualTests.html).  I can do it in a program called [POSTMAN](https://www.postman.com) that helps with API stuff, but I cannot work out how to take what I have in POSTMAN and code it into my VB.NET application.  I believe I may need to add a BODY to my **HTTPWebRequest** but don't know how.  Can anyone point me in the right direction.  New to API's. Thx.

This is the code I have so far - but missing the way to add:

- grant_type=password
- username=myemail@somedomain.com
- password=mypassword

```
    Public Function GetBoxAPIToken() As String
        Try
            Dim request As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create($"https://app.bic-boxtech.org/oauth/token")

            With request
                .Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Basic YmljYXBwOmJpY3NlY3JldGFwcA==")
                .Method = "POST"
                .ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

            End With
            Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
                Using streamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                    Dim jsonResponseText As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
                    Dim m As JArray = JArray.Parse(jsonResponseText)
                    Console.WriteLine(m.Item(0).Item("accessToken"))
                    Return m.Item(0).Item("accessToken")
                End Using

            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Catch error here...
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: Temporarily remove your try...catch to see if an error pops up.

Comment: Did that - return from response is BAD REQUEST